# MySQL Service won't start with error [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 4294963199 in space 0

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu, corruption

My MySQL installation on Ubuntu 18.04 crashed and now won't start.

The error log says

> Trying to access page number 4294963199 in space 0, space name
>   innodb_system, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0,
>   len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup,
>   please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have
>   in the MySQL server.

Some Googling led me to believe this could be a corruption issue.

I edited the mysql config adding `innodb_force_recovery = 5` to the mysqld section which allows the server to start.

I was then able to run a mysqlcheck to check for corruption:

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases
```

Which showed all tables as ok (Although one reported `note: The storage engine for the table doesn't support check`)

Where do I go from here? The error log is suggesting corruption but mysqlcheck does not find any

Comment: "_Where do I go from here?_". If the server is still unable to start, you restore your data from the most recent backup and carry on.

Comment: How do I know which database I need to restore though?

Comment: MySQL "database" is a misnomer; it is just a schema, a logical namespace, inside the real MySQL instance. Judging by the error message ("space 0, space name innodb_system"), one of the system tables is corrupted, so you'll probably want to restore everything you have a backup of. [Somewhat related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183862/trying-to-solve-outside-tablespace-bounds-mysql-error-but-recovering-table-wi)