# Unable to recover MySQL 5.6 (InnoDB) database

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery, docker, ibdata

I've tried multiple different suggestions from other questions on here, with no luck...

This is a MySQL database running version 5.6.41, using the InnoDB engine, and the instance is running out of a Docker image. (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=tags&page=1&name=5.6.41) The image has my main database files (ibd and frm files) symlinked outside of the instance.

Here's the error:

```
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 0 in space 842,
InnoDB: space name <DATABASE>/<TABLE>,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
2019-09-12 14:59:26 7f2fe639e700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139843702744832 in file fil0fil.cc line 5666`
```

I attempted to use the `innodb_force_recovery` flag at all values (including 5-6). The error above happens when I use the mysql command line tool, and enter `DROP TABLE <DB>.<TABLE>`. The main problem is I cannot access the database to even attempt any of these recovery options any more.

This likely started happening following a host (MacOS 10.13.6) system crash which caused an unexpected shutdown of my Docker container during file write.

I believe either my `ibdata` or `ib_logfiles` are corrupt, but I can't figure out how to recover the database without wiping everything clean and recovering from a `mysqldump` (which may not even work).

I don't care about the data in this table, I can recover data from a development/testing MySQL server. I'd just like to not go through the hassle of starting everything from scratch.

Here are a few other stackex q's I've looked at: [MySQL can't delete table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183200/mysql-cant-delete-table)

[Trying to solve "outside tablespace bounds" MySQL error, but recovering table with mysqldump fails](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183862/trying-to-solve-outside-tablespace-bounds-mysql-error-but-recovering-table-wi)

Any suggestions?
(If you need more info, like my variable settings/`my.cnf` files, or database structure info, please ask)

Comment: Upvoting solely due to your willingness to edit the question in the event more information is needed.  I know jack and squat about MySQL, so I'm of no help, but welcome to DBA.SE and hopefully we can help you out!